# Google App Engine Error:"Missing value for property jvmargs" in netbeans 8.02

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

Am trying to run the sample book web app using GAE. but am getting **Missing value for property jvmargs** error from GAE output window.

I successfully installed GAE plugin from http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/NetBeans8/updates.xml

my netbeans version is 8.02 and am using JDK 1.7.0_49. i have tried to use JDK 1.6.0_45 but still getting the same error.

What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also facing the issue

Comment: @Harikrishnan    

This is code to add within appengine-web.xml :

`<!-- TODO review code for thread-safety. -->
<threadsafe>false</threadsafe>`

Comment: @Harikrishnan    did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. It worked in Netbeans after this fix. But it is working with eclipse without this fix.

Comment: After opened with eclipse, it seems working even giving threadsafe as true, but I cant start in debug mode

Comment: @Harikrishnan   what do you mean by saying you can't start in debug mode?

Comment: When I click on the debug button, Netbeans starts the debugger and server. but the debugger immediately closing. No errors in the console and server keeps running

Comment: @Harikrishnan   what happens when you run the project?